# How to design a transaction that calls nested functions and only commits if all called nested functions commit, e.g. abort if one subfunction fails?

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, supabase

How to design a transaction that calls nested functions and only commits if all called nested functions commit, e.g. abort if one subfunction fails?

For example, this transaction:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION unfollow(
    follower_id uuid,
    following_id uuid
)
    RETURNS void
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
    SECURITY INVOKER
AS
$$
BEGIN
        PERFORM delete_relationship(
    follower_id,
    following_id
        );
        PERFORM decrement_counter(
    following_id
            );

END;
$$;
```

should only commit if both update functions are successful. This works when I add to every database operation in the called functions a statement that checks if the previous CRUD operation was successful and raises an exception if unsucessful. Like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION delete_relationship(
    follower_id uuid,
    following_id uuid
)
    RETURNS void
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
    SECURITY INVOKER
AS
$$
BEGIN
    DELETE
    FROM
        following_profiles
    WHERE
          follower = follower_id
      AND following = following_id;

    IF NOT FOUND THEN
        ROLLBACK;
        -- Raise an exception to roll back the transaction
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'Error in unfollow_transaction: %', SQLERRM;
    END IF;
END;
$$;
```

If I do not raise that exception, the transaction commits even one of the sub function fails.

Is there a smarter way to do this? Is it possible to make functions raise an exception by default if a CRUD operation fails without mentioning it every time, e.g. is there a way to avoid writing all the exception statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Failing to select update or delete rows that match a where clause is not exceptional.

However you don't need to rollback anything. Any exception - whether from the dB itself or your code does that. That is basically the whole point of transactions. Everything works or nothing does.

---

Additon in response to the comment below.

It's not exceptional to affect zero rows because... there's nothing unusual about that.

```sql
UPDATE enquiries SET status='expired'
WHERE status='pending' AND query_date < CURRENT_DATE - 365
```

That's the sort of query that you might run every night from a scheduled task. Why exactly should it throw an exception if there aren't any old pending enquiries? That's a perfectly normal situation.

Comment: Makes sense - in that case. But in my case, if the delete/update operation does not delete/update an item, it indicates that something went wrong. So there is no other way then raising errors manually, correct?

Comment: The failure is an *application level* error, so no, afraid not